# Sympy not properly displaying conjugate of square root of real

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, sympy, simplify

I keep getting expressions like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9QDe.png), despite declaring these symbols as reals.

The code to reproduce is:

```
import sympy as sp
delta = sp.Symbol('delta', real=True)
f = sp.sqrt(1/delta)
prod = sp.conjugate(f)*f
prod.subs(delta,delta)
```

I expected to get 1/delta

Also trying `simplify()` does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official SymPy Docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy.functions.elementary.complexes.conjugate) for `conjugate`, it looks like the function is supposed to return the *complex conjugate* for its input. In other words, it takes the [complex part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) of the number and flips the sign.

In your example, you are taking the square root of a variable. If `delta = -1`, then the resulting conjugate *could be unreal* and thus different than if `delta` was any other integer. Thus, `SymPy` wraps the result in a `conjugate` object.

If you want to tell Sympy that your variable `delta` is positive (and thus `f` must be real), then you should define it as `delta = sp.Symbol('delta', real=True, positive=True)`.

Comment: It is sufficient to say only `positive=True` because every positive number is a real number.